# How to program an iterator in scala without using a mutable variable?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iterator

I want to implement the iterator trait but in the functional way, ie, without using a var. How to do that?

Suppose I have an external library where I get some elements by calling a function `getNextElements(numOfElements: Int):Array[String]` and I want to implement an Iterator using that function but without using a variable indicating the "current" array (in my case, the var buffer). How can I implement that in the functional way?

```
class MyIterator[T](fillBuffer: Int => Array[T]) extends Iterator[T] {
    var buffer: List[T] = fillBuffer(10).toList

    override def hasNext(): Boolean = {
        if (buffer.isEmpty) buffer = fillBuffer(10).toList
        buffer.nonEmpty
    }

    override def next(): T = {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException()

        val elem: T = buffer.head
        buffer = buffer.tail
        elem
    }
}

class Main extends App {
    def getNextElements(num: Int): Array[String] = ???

    val iterator = new MyIterator[String](getNextElements)

    iterator.foreach(println)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterators are mutable, at least without an interface that also returns a state variable, so you can't in general implement the interface directly without some sort of mutation.

That being said, there are some very useful functions in the `Iterator` companion object that let you hide the mutation, and make the implementation cleaner. I would implement yours something like:

```
Iterator.continually(getNextElements(10)).flatten
```

This calls `getNextElements(10)` whenever it needs to fill the buffer. The `flatten` changes it from an `Iterator[Array[A]]` to an `Iterator[A]`.

Note this returns an infinite iterator. Your question didn't say anything about detecting the end of your source elements, but I would usually implement that using `takeWhile`.  For example, if `getNextElements` returns an empty array when there are no more elements, you can do:

```
 Iterator.continually(getNextElements(10)).takeWhile(!_.isEmpty).flatten
```

Comment: Other alternative would be to use a **Stream** _(or a **LazyList**)_ instead of an **Iterator**, which the first one can be pure.

Comment: I'm in no way familiar with the iterator interface. But since state based looping and recursion are proven to be equivalent in their expressive power, I'd assume that there is at least a theoretical possibility to implement it using nothing but recursion. Correct me if I'm wrong though.